# Is there any publication of Bombieri about the standard conjectures on algebraic cycles?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, motives, algebraic-cycles

In *"Standard conjectures of algebraic cycles"* Grothendieck says:

> "... These [Standard conjectures] are not really new, and they were worked out about three years ago independently by Bombieri and myself..."

Did Bombieri publish something of this work?

Comment: Nice question! I hope you don't mind my edit…

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's Bombieri's [publication list](http://www.unipi.it/ateneo/comunica/cerimonie/honoris/pubblicazioni.htm) and there seems to be just one paper that could qualify [1], unfortunately not available online. A later paper with Andreotti [2] is online, but does not quite seem to be the one.

[1] E. Bombieri, [Varieta algebriche omeomorfe](http://www.worldcat.org/title/symposia-mathematica-vol-2-convegni-del-1968-analisi-funzionale-e-geometria/oclc/84461640) (1968).

[2] A. Andreotti and E. Bombieri, [Sugli omeomorfismi delle varieta algebraiche](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/ASNSP/ASNSP_1969_3_23_3/ASNSP_1969_3_23_3_431_0/ASNSP_1969_3_23_3_431_0.pdf) (1969).

Incidentally, it seems Grothendieck was alerted to Bombieri's work by Serre in a [letter from 1964:](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search?index=books&linkCode=qs&keywords=9780821834244)

[image]